# How to show dinamically a react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working in a React project and I need to render some Components based on a layout.

--asumme you have an array that tells you the components you need to render:

```
Layout1 = ['Events', 'Photo', 'News']
```

--And a function that, depends on the module, render the especific component with some data:

```
layout1.forEach(function(layout) {
  someFuncions(layout, somedata);
});

someFunction = (layout, data) => {
  layout.forEach( function(Comp) {
    if(Comp == 'Events') {
      return (<Events module-data={data} />)
    } else if(Comp == 'Photo') {
      return (<Photo module-data={data} />)
    } else if(Comp == 'News') {
      return (<News module-data={data} />)
    }
  });
}
```

-- Since it is possible to have many components I want to find a way to avoid the "if" function to determine what component should I render.

How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approaching it by creating a map for your components, then doing a lookup when rendering.

```
const components = {
    Events, // Shorthand for 'Events': Events
    Photo,
    News
};

const layout = ['Events', 'Photo'];

const someFunction = (layout, data) =>
    layout.map((name) => {
        const Component = components[name];
        return <Component module-data={data} />;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested and it was the best approach. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch` similar syntex but maybe a little cleaner.

```
switch(comp) {
    case 'Events':
        return (<Events module-data={data} />)
    case 'Photo':
        return (<Photo module-data={data} />)
    case 'News':
        return (<News module-data={data} />) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the component in the array directly.

```
import Events from 'path/to/Events'
import Photo from 'path/to/Photo'
import News from 'path/to/News'

Layout1 = [Events, Photo, News]
```

And then wherever you call the function.

From your original question, it seems like the layout1 in your question is an array of Layout1 like arrays.

```
layout1.forEach(function(layout) {
  someFuncions(layout, somedata);
});

someFunction = (layout, data) => {

  // returning from forEach won't result in anything. you probably want to map
  layout.forEach( function(Component) {
    return (<Component module-data={data} />)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a javascript object that maps the layout to the desired component? This way, it's clear that you intend to render a different component depending on the layout.

See the following example:

```js
const someFunction = (layout, data) => {
  const componentMap = {
    'Events': <Events module-data={data} />,
    'Photo': <Photo module-data={data} />,
    'News': <News module-data={data} />
  }

  return componentMap[layout];
}
```